# Responding to media button when media player is closed

Tags: applications, audio, media-button

According to what is clearly described here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons 
when I press the media button (PTT button in my unihertz Titan Pocket) after completely closing my media player (foobar2000 app permits this) the OS automatically resurrects my media player and asks it to play.
This drives me nuts.

If I stop the music and enter a silent room, I always risk to start playback (possibly loudly) by just badly handling my phone. This is unacceptable to my standards of education.

I see some possible counteractions:

- ask the app developer to modify the code in order to set a null media button receiver at app exit
- reduce the media volume everytime I completely stop my media player
- write an app by myself that sets a null media button receiver

Really there is not a system settings option that could affect this awkward-by-design behaviour?

Comment: I disabled mediaButton broadcast receiver for a music app I use. Launched the music app, then closed it (swiped away), and apparently it still received media button and resumed playback. This is a bug in my Android 10 I think. Android should not let an app do something when its corresponding component is disabled. // BTW, as a workaround you can setup an automation app to reduce volume level to 0 once the user stops media playback.

Comment: Android 11 behaves the same as 10. Not a bug but a "feature".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by installing [AIMP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aimp.player) that sets a null media button receiver when the application is properly closed (not only paused or put in background).

Comment: AIMP could be not the only one player that implements this feature. I found this but others might exist.